# @types/jsonwebtoken 7.2.1 gives strange type error. Why?

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, json-web-token

I'm using `node v6.10.3`, `typescript v2.3.4`, and `jsonwebtoken v7.4.1`.  Up until today, I was using type information from `@types/jsonwebtoken v7.2.0`, but I upgraded to `@types/jsonwebtoken v7.2.1` and now when I run my application it gives the error:

```
src/reports/password-reset/password-reset.report.ts(18,23): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ ownerId: string; passwordResetToken: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | object | Buffer'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'ownerId' does not exist in type 'string | object | Buffer'.
```

For the line of code:

```
let token = sign({ownerId:passwordResetRequest.ownerId, passwordResetToken: true }, 
    configuration.secret, {
    expiresIn: timeToLiveInSeconds
});
```

This error does not arise with `@types/jsonwebtoken v7.2.0`, only `v7.2.1`.

Strangely, if I build my project within Visual Studio Code (same version of TypeScript), it shows that same error but when I click on the error and go to the relevant file, the error goes away and VS Code is happy with the syntax.

Also, the error message is telling me that my object `{ownerId:passwordResetRequest.ownerId, passwordResetToken: true }` can't be passed to a parameter of type `string | object | Buffer`, but it is clearly an object.  I have no idea why it even cares what the contents of the object is.

Also note that it works fine - like the actual `jsonwebtoken` library is fine - it is just the `@type` information that is causing the problem during build.

So I've just reverted back to `@types/jsonwebtoken v7.2.0` and everything works fine.  Not a big issue, but what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

OK - looks like this is covered [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/17007).  (Bug in TypeScript)

Leaving the question up in case anyone comes looking here with the same problem.  Should have looked at the GitHub issues list first apparently.